how to give High Resolution in Image
I am using image in my application but while capturing i am getting blur image
my capture image code is
 private async Task CaptureImage()
 {
     int maxAllowedImages = 3;
     int currentImageCount = iTSimageCopy != null ? iTSimageCopy.Images.Count : 0;

     if (currentImageCount >= maxAllowedImages)
     {
         Snackbar.Add($"Part number already has the maximum allowed images ({maxAllowedImages}).", Severity.Warning);
         return;
     }

     DialogParameters parameters = new DialogParameters();
     var options = new DialogOptions
         {
             FullWidth = true,
             DisableBackdropClick = true,
             Position = DialogPosition.Center
         };
     DialogResult result = await DialogService.Show<EditCaptureImgDialog>("Capture Image", parameters, options).Result;

     if (!result.Canceled)
     {
         string imageUri = result.Data.ToString();
         byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(imageUri.Split(',')[1]);

         if (bytes.Length > Constants.IMAGE_MAX_SIZE)
         {
             Snackbar.Add($"The Captured image exceeds the maximum size limit : 20 MB.", Severity.Warning);
         }
         else
         {
             byte[] imageStreamToBytes;

             using (var image = SixLabors.ImageSharp.Image.Load(bytes))
             {
                 using (MemoryStream outputStream = new MemoryStream())
                 {
                     var encoder = new SixLabors.ImageSharp.Formats.Jpeg.JpegEncoder { Quality = 85 };
                     image.Save(outputStream, encoder);

                     imageStreamToBytes = outputStream.ToArray();
                 }
             }

             iTSimageCopy.Images.Add(new Image { Data = imageStreamToBytes });
             iTSimage = iTSimageCopy;
         }

        
     }
 }

and My js function is
async function startVideo(src) {
    try {
        const permission = await checkCameraPermission();
        if (permission === 'prompt' || permission === 'granted') {
            navigator.getUserMedia(
                { video: true, audio: false },
                function (localMediaStream) {
                    let video = document.getElementById(src);
                    video.srcObject = localMediaStream;
                    video.onloadedmetadata = function (e) {
                        video.play();
                    };
                },
                function (err) {
                    console.error('Error accessing camera:', err);
                    throw err; // Propagate the error
                }
            );
        } else {
            console.error('Camera permission denied.');
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error starting video:', error);
    }
}



function getFrame(src, dest, dotnetHelper) {
    let video = document.getElementById(src);
    let canvas = document.getElementById(dest);

    // Check if the video and canvas elements exist before drawing the image
    if (video && canvas) {
        canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(video, 0, 0, 150, 150);

        // Resize the image on the canvas
        let resizedCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        resizedCanvas.width = 200; // Set desired width
        resizedCanvas.height = 200; // Set desired height
        let ctx = resizedCanvas.getContext('2d');
        ctx.drawImage(canvas, 0, 0, resizedCanvas.width, resizedCanvas.height);

        // Convert the resized image to base64 JPEG format
        let dataUrl = resizedCanvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");

        // Invoke the .NET method with the resized image data
        dotnetHelper.invokeMethodAsync('ProcessImage', dataUrl);
    } else {
        console.error('Video or canvas element not found.');
    }
}


How to give highest quality on image so that when I will capture the image I will get  good quality of image. both my phone and laptop image is displaying blur while capture image
Home to increase the image quality

To improve the quality of captured images, you can try to set a higher Aspect_ratio when calling navigator.getUserMedia, such as 1920x1080 (1080p) or 1280x720 (720p), etc.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Aspect_ratio
navigator.getUserMedia( { video: { width: 1280, height: 720 }, audio: false },
And set the image format and quality parameters. The encoderOptions parameter is a number between 0 and 1 that specifies the image quality, with 1.0 representing the highest quality.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL#setting_image_quality_with_jpegs
When using SixLabors.ImageSharp, you can set a higher quality parameter. The default value is usually 75.
https://docs.sixlabors.com/api/ImageSharp/SixLabors.ImageSharp.Formats.Jpeg.JpegEncoder.html#SixLabors_ImageSharp_Formats_Jpeg_JpegEncoder_Quality

I tried this approach, but I'm still encountering the same issue. I found another solution that improves image quality, but the capture process is taking a long time.
